# Linux hangs on shutdown!

Tags: shutdown

I have a really bad problem!! my machine doesn't shutdown with Ubuntu, peppermint, or any Linux distro!

I need help, when i turn on my computer with Ubuntu, all appears to be fine, but when i want to shutdown, using `shutdown now`, `systemctl poweroff` or similar.. my machine just won't shutdown, i noticed my CPU fan is running with less speed that when my machine is on, and the keyboard and mouse it still "running" they have the lights on but doesn't work.

Please some help, I'm desperate!!

```
Memoria:        3,8G        640M        2,4G        106M        792M        2,8G
Swap:          2,0G          0B        2,0G



 # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=e7c8b88b-61fb-4bfe-88b8-93d2ebdc32b0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=B8F7-9A9C  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0`
```

Thanks!

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Select shutdown from the power menu, and then hit the ESC key. Tell me what you see. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Try to add `nomodeset` to kernel boot options

Comment: up @LeonidMew. that is the solution.

Comment: @heynnema i tried about 16.04 and 18.04, linux mint, etc.. do you want to show the logs when i shutdown the computer right? because i see all things are 'ok' and it hangs on 'starting shutdown'.
Leonid, when i can find the kernel boot options?

Comment: If you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, will it shutdown properly? What make/model computer? Edit your question and show me `free -h`.

Comment: @heynnema if i use a live CD it shutdown properly, and its a MEDION akoya from mediamarkt, and the free -h what makes? i need to do it after the shutdown?

Comment: @normal no, you type `free -h` in a `terminal` window, then you copy/paste that output as an edit to your question. Also show me `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: @heynnema edited.. and i need to say in a life CD WON'T shutdown too, i tested it and doesn't shutdown too.

Comment: @normal But, earlier you said that it DID shutdown properly. Which is it? You need to check for a BIOS update for your computer.

Comment: yes i know i say it, but i noticed it don't make it.. and a BIOS upgrade sounds dangerous, i never maked one..

Comment: See https://www.medion.com/gb/service/_lightbox/treiber.php?msn=30021507&prod=MEDION%20AKOYA%20S3409%20(MD%2060310)%20UK and http://www.medion.com/gb/service/_lightbox/treiber.php?stxt=bios

Comment: @heynnema a BIOS update? why?

Comment: @normal partly because of "my machine doesn't shutdown with Ubuntu, peppermint, or any Linux distro!".